# Values with the same coordinates in two matrix

Tags: matlab

There is some way to solve this problem without using a loop.
For example:

```
X = [1 1 
     1 2 
     1 3];

Y = [1 2 
     2 2];
```

And I need the following result:

```
result = [1 2]
```

I need to get values with the same coordinates.

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = intersect(X,Y, 'rows')
```